# How to use a user defined function in all excel without an additional operation?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I have a simple function that converts a range into `CSV` format. I am using this function every time and in every excel files. So I need this function to exist in all `Excel` workbooks default, no need extra load as `Excel's` default formulas (e.g `VLookUp`). How can I do that?

**User-Defined Function in Module:**

```
Public Function csvformat(r As range, seperator As String)
result = ""
For Each cell In r
result = result & cell & seperator
Next
result = Left(result, Len(result) - 1)
csvformat = result
End Function
```

Comment: You could use `TEXTJOIN` rather than a UDF if you have Excel 2016

Comment: By the way, `result = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(seperator))`

Comment: @CallumDA I have Office 2013 unfortunately

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-Custom-Functions-in-Excel-2007-2f06c10b-3622-40d6-a1b2-b6748ae8231f?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

> An easier way to make your custom functions available at all times is to store them in a separate workbook and then save that workbook as an add-in. You can then make the add-in available whenever you run Excel. Here’s how to do this:
>
> After you have created the functions you need, click the Microsoft Office Button, and click Save As.
>
> In the Save As dialog box, open the Save As Type drop-down list, and select Excel Add-In. Save the workbook under a recognizable name—such as MyFunctions—in the AddIns folder. (The Save As dialog box will propose that folder, so all you need to do is accept the default location.)
>
> After you have saved the workbook, click the Microsoft Office Button, and click Excel Options.
>
> In the Excel Options dialog box, click the Add-Ins category.
>
> In the Manage drop-down list, select Excel Add-Ins. Then click the Go button.
>
> In the Add-Ins dialog box, select the check box beside the name you used to save your workbook, as shown below.